# MKMapView makes the navigation bar gets transparent

Tags: mkmapview, uinavigationbar, ios7

I am porting my existing iOS 6 application to the new iOS 7. But whenever a MKMapView instance appears into the screen, my navigation bar loses its tint color.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Xcode;
2. Create a new Master-Detail Application;
3. Add the next line as the first one of the AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

   `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]`
4. Add the next line to the MasterViewController.m file:

   `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`
5. Finally, add the next lines to the MasterViewController.m cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

   `MKMapView *view = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:view];`
6. Build and Run

These are the results:

[image: Ok]     [image: Navigation bar got transparent]     [image: Issued UI]

Am I doing something wrong? 
What can I do to fix this issue?

Should I start using the Google Maps API instead?

Comment: This seems to be know to Apple. See here https://devforums.apple.com/message/858470#858470

Comment: Hi @Klaas, you are right. Thank you for sharing the devforums thread. Upvoted your comment.

Comment: I'm seeing this on the device (iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 5th gen), but not the simulator.

Comment: I also have this issue. To get around it I set the background image of the nav bar to an image of the color I wanted. You can then set it's alpha to whatever you want to get the transparency. The only thing that is missing is the blur effect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is fixed now (newest ios-Version). I got the error neither in the simulator nor on the device.

Answer (score 0):

dfine the size(width,height) of mapview before you use it and if not work then use it with enabled navigation controller in mapviewcontroller this may help you

Answer (score 0):

I put a `MKMapView` inside a `MyMapViewController` and applied auto layout constraints so it took all the available space. Whenever I push that view controller onto a `UINavigationController` the navigation bar becomes transparent.

My solution was to subclass `UINavigationController` and apply a fix in the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method.

```
class MainViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        delegate = self
        pushMyMapViewController()
    }

    private func pushMyMapViewController() {
        let myMapViewController = MyMapViewController()
        pushViewController(myMapViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension MainViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController is MyMapViewController {
            // Fix the issue with placing a MKMapView underneath the UINavigationBar causing the bar to become transparent.
            // This is due to the `scrollEdgeAppearance` change introduced in iOS 15.
            navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
        } else {
            navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = nil
        }
    }

}
```

You do not necessarily need to subclass `UINavigationController`. However I found it the best place to set the `scrollEdgeAppearance` to `standardAppearance` when the view controller containing the `MKMapView` is pushed onto the stack and set it back to `nil` when that view controller is popped off the stack.