# different frameworks depending on processor - google map iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7, 64-bit, mkmapview

I used a mkmap view in my app for some time, until I found out that theres a bug which causes the map to change the navigation bar and tab bar colours and translucence in iPhones older then 5.
reference :[MKMapView makes the navigation bar gets transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917888/mkmapview-makes-the-navigation-bar-gets-transparent)

so I have decided to use google maps sdk for iOS instead. but now I find out that they did not bother releasing a 64 bit version yet, so when i try to compile the app in the 64 simulator i get a " missing required architecture x86_64 in file "

So the question is:
How can I load the google map framework only for 86 and if its a 64(which means of course there will be no problem with the color since its a 5s phone) use mkmapview?

Comment: Does your app really need to be compiled for 64 bit processors? perhaps it is better to keep building the 32bit version for now since it will run on the 5S just fine.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the 5s came with the 32 framework as well. I would like to know the answer for general knowledge.